# Chemical reaction damaged finish on my dining table

Tags: wood, finish

I **seriously** damaged the finish on the TOP of my Ethan Allen Royal Charter dining room table.  The table about 42 years old.

It was sprayed with a aerosol dusting product (which now I know is a NO NO) and then I put a plastic cover on it not realizing the spray had not yet completely dried. I guess there was a chemical reaction as the finish is now soft & it can be removed with a finger nail. Much later I put a plastic table cloth on with a "flannel back"  and the fuzz actually stuck to the table in some areas.

I have tried Murphy's Oil soap on the table top but there of course was no improvement.

How can I fix this?

Elaine

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm guessing that repairing furniture finishes will be deemed off-topic here, but let's see what responses you get. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: this Q&A is more about house repairs than homekeeping.  You should probably ask this in https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/ , they will probably want to know what type of finish is on the table top. polyurethane, shellac, french polish, acrylic lacquer, etc... and they will be able to instruct you how to determine which it is.

Comment: Agreed that this would be in woodworking, but I'll just say it will be hard to recover the original finish from this, if at even possible. If it were my table, I'd carefully strip the top only with a something environmentally friendly like CistrusStrip.  Then determine if any original stain was stripped  off as well, do any color (stain) corrections you feel need to be done and refinish with a good durable finish of your choice, I like pre-cat lacquer, but it's nasty to work with and you need to spray it. Sorry, but I think re-finishing is your best option.

Answer (score 1):

Strip and refinish is likely the only way forward with an acceptable outcome.

The plastic cover is more of a no-no than aerosol dusting products, really. On the other hand, there's no particular need for aerosol dusting products, ever, so...

The combination of the two is obviously bad.